# How can i find all comments in code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to find all comments in all classes in project, like // or /* */ or /** */

Comment: Regex search? Does that not work?

Comment: you can use ctrl+shift+f to find in whole project.

Comment: i mean, do Android Studio have an option or interface feature like TODO option in bottom toolbar? For example, anytime before i commit code, i want to check it for comments and delete obsolete and temporary notes. Thank you, Ctrl+Shift+F is good solution! I used Search button in top toolbar of Android Studio, but seems like its completely different search option :(